# Pandas skipping lines (stop warnings from showing)

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV file in Python this way using Pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

I am getting:

> Skipping line 6: expected 4 fields, saw 6

How do I stop this warnings from showing up?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

`data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: Thanks! I was looking exactly this

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **warn_bad_lines :** boolean, default True
>
> If error_bad_lines is False, and warn_bad_lines is True, a warning for
>     each “bad line” will be output.

So set `warn_bad_lines=False`

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Haha - I love when answers are so obvious two people can write almost identical responses at the exact same time.

Comment: @jack6e It's pretty great. I was vacillating on whether to include the quote, too; could've been closer.